# Erlang : Finding multiple Max values of a list

Tags: algorithm, list, functional-programming, erlang

first of all i don't know anything about Erlang, we are me and a colleague rewriting a Map Reduce in couchDB from JS to Erlang as a test.

In input we have something like :

```
{[
    {<<"score">>, {[ {<<"max">>, SCORE_MAX} ]} },
    {<<"points">>, {[ {<<"max">>, POINTS_MAX}, {<<"total">>, POINTS_TOTAL} ]} },
    {<<"time">>, {[ {<<"total">>, TIME_TOTAL} ]} },
    {<<"success">>, SUCCESS},
//etc..
]}
```

We would like to traverse the list[ [score, progress, points ] ] and output the "max(score), max(progress), max(points)" of this list.

So far the only thing we succeed doing is one loop per max(value) or sum(value) we want For example :

```
        PROGRESS_MAX = lists:max(lists:map(fun({Value}) ->
            {Progress} = proplists:get_value(<<"progress">>, Value),
            proplists:get_value(<<"max">>, Progress)
        end, Values)),

        LEVEL_MAX = lists:max(lists:map(fun({Value}) ->
            {Level} = proplists:get_value(<<"level">>, Value),
            Max = proplists:get_value(<<"max">>, Level, 0)
        end, Values)),

        POINTS_TOTAL = lists:sum(lists:map(fun({Value}) ->
            {Points} = proplists:get_value(<<"points">>, Value),
            proplists:get_value(<<"total">>, Points)
        end, Values)),
```

Any idea how we can do it in a more efficient way ? 
because here we are simply doing a loop (lists:map) for every kind of value we want .. and our mind is too tight to procedural programming and mutable variables so we can't figure out an efficient way of doing it..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated the answer to reflect the comments**

I have taken the liberty to modify the input data in order to make the answer compile.

```
    InputList = [{[
   {<<"score">>, {[ {<<"max">>, 2} ]} },
   {<<"points">>, {[ {<<"max">>, 3}, {<<"total">>, 7} ]} },
   {<<"time">>, {[ {<<"total">>, 4} ]} },
   {<<"success">>, 9}
   ]},
 {[
   {<<"score">>, {[ {<<"max">>, 2} ]} },
   {<<"points">>, {[ {<<"max">>, 3}, {<<"total">>, 7} ]} },
   {<<"time">>, {[ {<<"total">>, 4} ]} },
   {<<"success">>, 9}
   ]}],
lists:foldl(fun({L0}, Dict0)->
                    lists:foldl(fun({E, {L}}, Dict1)->
                                        Max=proplists:get_value(<<"max">>, L, 0),
                                        dict:update(E, fun(OldValue)-> OldValue + Max end, Max, Dict1);
                                   (_, Dict1) -> Dict1 
                                end, Dict0, L0)
           end, dict:new(), InputList).
```

Comment: I think i did not exposed the problem correctly as we are within a couchview.
But the input is an array of the example in the head.

So kind of, we need the 'Max of the max'.

At work we moved on and splitted into more views to simplify everything (erlang syntaxe etc..) but for the sake of understanding how it can be done using pure Erlang, i will update later.. (this week end likely when i'll have time to setup the problem outside of couchdb)

Anyway thanks for trying :)

Comment: I have updated the answer to match up to your comments.

Comment: Awesome ! that is exactly what i hoped we could do in erlang..

Will try it the next time i have something similar (dict & dict:update is the awesomeness here for us)